# The scroll does not get blocked when I activate the modal on my page from Safari iOS 17

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile, mobile-safari

I have a page with several cards, which generate a scroll. Each card will have a button that, when clicked, allows you to view the details of that specific card (for practical purposes, only one card has a button).

Upon clicking the button, a modal opens, and the scroll, displaying all the cards, disappears. When clicking the "close modal" button, everything returns to the initial state, the scroll returns, and you can continue viewing the cards. This works well in desktop browsers.

When I open my page on my iPhone (iOS 17) with Safari, there is an issue. If the toolbar or the page's address bar is in its natural state (i.e., with its full size showing the blue buttons), opening the modal locks the scroll, and closing the modal returns everything to normal. However, if, before opening the modal, I swipe down, the toolbar will become smaller (displaying only the page's name). Doing that and then opening the modal, for some reason, the scroll continues to work (even though the modal is open).

Something interesting: if, upon entering the page, you hide the toolbar in settings, everything works perfectly.

I'm attaching a video showing what is happening. I've been trying to solve it for hours :(

Here's a video of my issue: https://veed.io/view/5a1f63ee-223a-42a5-99a8-318115f9c88a

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        
        <section class="cards-container">
            <div class="card N1"><button id="openModal">Open modal</button></div>
            <div class="card N2">card 2</div>
            <div class="card N3">Card 3</div>
            <div class="card N4">Card 4</div>
            <div class="card N5">Card 5</div>
            <div class="card N6">Card 6</div>
            <div class="card N7">Card 7</div>
            <div class="card N8">Card 8</div>
            <div class="card N9">Card 9</div>
            <div class="card N10">Card 10</div>
        </section>
    </main>
    
    <section class="modal-container" id="modalContainer">
        <div class="modal">
            <button id="closeModal">Close modal</button>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

main {
    z-index: 1;
}
.cards-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
    min-height: 100svh;
}

.card {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    width: 150px;
    height: 160px;

    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
#closeModal {
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(224, 36, 36);
}
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-style: none;
    
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
}
.card.N2 {
    background-color: rgb(83, 207, 83);
}

.card.N4 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.card.N6 {
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
.card.N7 {
    background-color:brown;
}
.card.N8 {
    background-color: aqua;
}
.card.N9 {
    background-color: chartreuse;
}
.card.N10 {
    background-color: blueviolet;
}


/* styles to modal */

.modal-container {
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: none;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.modal-container.active {
    display: block;
}

.modal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

    position: absolute;
    
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;

    background-color: rgb(88, 253, 253);
}
```

JS Vanilla code:

```
const btnOpenModal = document.getElementById('openModal');
const btnCloseModal = document.getElementById('closeModal')
const modal = document.getElementById('modalContainer');

let modalAbierto = false;

btnOpenModal.addEventListener('click', function() {
    modal.classList.add('active');
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'

});

btnCloseModal.addEventListener('click', function() {
    modal.classList.remove('active');
    document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'

})
```

Thanks guys!